# Qual a utilidade da palavra-chave extern em c?

Tags: c

Vi no site com link abaixo que no padrão ANSI C existe a palavra-chave extern, mas nunca vi sendo utilizada na prática. O que ela faz exatamente?

http://tigcc.ticalc.org/doc/keywords.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cara, após pesquisas entendi que o extern serve para indicar que uma variável já foi definida em uma outra parte do programa como um todo.
Por exemplo, se você divide um código gigante em 2 partes. Você deverá indicar para o compilador que você está utilizando essas variáveis em um bloco (arquivo 2) mas elas foram inicializadas em outro bloco (código 1).

por exemplo:

Código 1:

```
int count;
float sum;
int main(void)
{
    ...
    return 0;
}
```

Código 2:

```
extern int count;
extern float sum;
int RetornaCount(void)
{
    return count;
}
```

Segue um link que explica bem melhor que eu: http://mtm.ufsc.br/~azeredo/cursoC/aulas/ca20.html

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Correto. E uma das utilidades dos arquivos .h é justamente conter as declarações de variáveis com extern, para evitar erros de copiar e colar.